# QObject::connect: no such signal. Also, Qtimer not calling

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-quick

I have a class, myClass:

```
class myClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QQuickWidget* widget;
    QString mystring;
    myClass (QQuickWidget* quickWidget, QString string);
    void myfunction();

public slots:
    void slot();
signals:
    void clicked();
};

myClass::myClass(QQuickWidget* quickWidget, QString string) : 
    widget(quickWidget), mystring(string)
{
    QTimer::singleShot(60000, this, SLOT(slot()));
    myfunction();
}

void myClass::slot()
{

}

void myClass::myfunction()
{
    widget->setVisible(true);
    widget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qmlsource.qml"));
    connect(widget, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slot()));
}
```

What I want to do is to call the `slot()` function 60 seconds after I create a myClass object. That doesn't happen. Also, at the connect line I get

```
QObject::connect: No such signal QQuickWidget::clicked()
```

message.

I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: qt4 ?  You use `widget` as the SIGNAL not `this` so does `widget->clicked()` also exist?  I think not.  Does using `connect(this, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(slot()));` remove the "No such signal ..." message ?

Comment: widget is a QQuickWidget object, so how can I create widget->clicked()?

Comment: Well maybe you don't need to connect `clicked` anyway for the goal to invoke myClass::slot() 60 seconds after the class is instated.  How do you know it does not get invoked?  Since the method is empty.

Comment: @Darryl Yes, using this as a parameter does remove the message, but is not working as I hopped. I am trying to call the clicked() function from my qml where I have onClicked: { clicked(); }

Comment: @DarrylMiles I have a breakpoint in the function

Comment: You are running QApplication.exec() event loop?  and waiting around in there for at least 60 seconds?  Your QTimer should occur.  As for the QQuickWidget matter that is not really part of the original problem you posed.

Comment: @DarrylMiles I don't know what QApplication.exec() event loop is. I did the tests using one second instead of 60 and doesn't work. I'm sorry about also mentioning the QQuickWidget matter

Comment: Then you have larger problems with getting this example to work.  Which is not covered by your original question on SO.  Maybe post the entire program as a new SO question ?

Comment: @DarrylMiles I am trying to solve these two problems at first. Your suggestion with the parameters helped me with the first one, thank you. I will formulate another SO question regarding the other problems.

Comment: QTimer's only fire via the QEventLoop and this is expected by default in all Qt applications, as the main loop of the application `QApplication.exec()`.  See any of the many documented examples.  This is fundamental to how Qt works for any normal event driven application.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you have a few issues here.

**1. QWidget**

The big one is that QWidget (which QQUickWidget inherits from) does not have a signal called "clicked", so the message `QObject::connect: No such signal QQuickWidget::clicked()` is quite right ;)

What you need to do is create your own object that inherits from QQuickWidget and then re-implement/overload the function `void QWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)` and/or `void QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * event)`

These are the functions that are called in the widget that you can then emit your signal. Which means you also need to add a new signal into you your widget. So your new class header may look a bit like (just including the main elements):

```
class MyQQuickWidget: public QQuickWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyQQuickWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:
    void clicked();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

};
```

And then in your implementation:

```
void MyQQuickWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        emit clicked();
    }
}
```

Then when you connect your MyQQuickWidget signal clicked() to MyClass slot slot() it will connect ok.

**2. QTimer**

It looks like your timer should fire... but there appears to be no debug in the slot `slot()` so how would you know if this is working or not?